# Next.js dynamic import with server-side-rendering turned off not working on production build

Tags: reactjs, next.js, leaflet, server-side-rendering

I'm currently building a site using the leaflet package. This package however needs the window object. That's why I'm importing a component made with leaflet as a dynamic component with ssr turned off. Just like this:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
   const MapWithNoSSR = dynamic(() => import("../../map"), {
             ssr: false
 });
 
export default function faqOnly(props){
 ...
 return (<> <MapWithNoSSR /></>)
 }
```

Map component looks like this:

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { OpenStreetMapProvider } from 'leaflet-geosearch';
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility/dist/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility.css'
import "leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const L = dynamic(() => import("leaflet"), {
      ssr: false,
      suspense: true,
      loading: () => <p>...</p>
    });


function Map(props) {


  useEffect(async () => {
    if(window === undefined) return
    const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();
     const results = await provider.search({ query: props.adress });
     if(results.length > 0 == true){
      var map = L.map('map', {
          center: [results[0].y, results[0].x],
          zoom: 18,
          layers: [
              L.tileLayer('https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth_dark/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
                  attribution: ''
              }),
          ]
      })
      L.marker([results[0].y, results[0].x]).addTo(map)
  }else{
    document.getElementById("map").style.display = "none"
  }
  }, [])


    return <div id="map" style={{ height: "30vh"}}></div>

}

export default Map;
```

And I get this error when I run `npm run build`:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at E:\Github\Planer\rl-planer\node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.js:230:19
    at E:\Github\Planer\rl-planer\node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.js:7:66
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Github\Planer\rl-planer\node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.js:10:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Github\Planer\rl-planer\node_modules\leaflet-geosearch\dist\geosearch.js:1:7) {
  type: 'ReferenceError'
}
```

This works fine in development, but when I try to build the project (next build), it throws a "window is not defined" error inside the leaflet package, which it hasn't been doing before when I was working on it in development mode.

I looked through other questions here, but it seems like moving the dynamic import outside the component fixed it for everyone but me. Am I just stupid or what's the problem here?

Comment: Are you importing leaflet anywhere outside the `Map` component? Can you show us the full error stack?

Comment: Nope, its just inside the map component

Comment: I also updated the question with all the necessary stuff

Comment: As far as I know `next/dynamic` is only for importing react components. So you can not import `leaflet` like this. But you also don't need to. Just getting `MapWithNoSSR` via `next/danamic` on the faq page should be all you need to avoid loding it on the server.

Comment: The error comes from `leaflet-geosearch`, that isn't being dynamically imported on the client-side only.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't need `next/dynamic` at all and can just use [simple js dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports) inside the `useEffect` function body.

(`useEffect` will only run on the client)

Nextjs has an example that looks pretty similar: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import. (the first on the page with fuse.js)

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { OpenStreetMapProvider } from 'leaflet-geosearch';
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility/dist/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility.css'
import "leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility";

function Map(props) {
  useEffect(async () => {
    const L = await import("leaflet")
    const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();
    const results = await provider.search({ query: props.adress });

    if(results.length > 0 == true) {
      var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [results[0].y, results[0].x],
        zoom: 18,
        layers: 
          [
            L.tileLayer(
              'https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth_dark/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png',
              { attribution: ''}
            ),
          ]
      })
      L.marker([results[0].y, results[0].x]).addTo(map)
    } else {
      document.getElementById("map").style.display = "none"
    }
  }, [])


  return <div id="map" style={{ height: "30vh"}}></div>
}

export default Map;
```

## Updated

Okay so maybe trying to move all js that requires window in a useEffect hook is a bit messy.
Seams easier to just import the whole component client only.
To me your example code looks good – apart from the fact that you import leaflet dynamically again in the map file:

page.jsx

```js
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const MapWithNoSSR = dynamic(() =>
  import("../../map"), { ssr: false });
 
export default function faqOnly(props){
  ...
  return <MapWithNoSSR />
}
```

map.jsx

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { OpenStreetMapProvider } from 'leaflet-geosearch';
import L from 'leaflet'
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility/dist/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility.css'
import "leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility";

function Map(props) {
  useEffect(async () => {
    const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();
    const results = await provider.search({ query: props.adress });

    if(results.length > 0 == true) {
      var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [results[0].y, results[0].x],
        zoom: 18,
        layers: 
          [
            L.tileLayer(
              'https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth_dark/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png',
              { attribution: ''}
            ),
          ]
      })
      L.marker([results[0].y, results[0].x]).addTo(map)
    } else {
      document.getElementById("map").style.display = "none"
    }
  }, [])


  return <div id="map" style={{ height: "30vh"}}></div>
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: Nope still gives me the error

Comment: @juliomalves is right… There are other imports also needing to run only client side such as leaflet-geosearch and leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility. So you could load all those in useEffect but this might not be the best solution…

Answer (score 0):

what I did was to create a `Map` component just like you did which contains every module of `leaflet` that uses `window` and then import that component with dynamic import of nextjs. In my case I did not use dynamic import for `leaflet` module but only for importing the `Map` component.